# Why CAML query isn't working on text lookup

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm using `CAMLQuery:'<Query>' + 
     '<Where>' +
     '<Contains>' +
        '<FieldRef Name="Course" />' +
        '<Value Type="Lookup">' + filtertext + '</Value>' +
    '</Contains>'+
   '</Where>'+
   '</Query>',`

```
 CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Date' /><FieldRef Name='Course' /></ViewFields>",
```

I'm trying to use the above to filter a SharePoint list.
The Course column contains text like and its a lookup e.g: "Lead the Way" with spaces
But not returning any result

Any ideas and Thanks

Comment: Remember when querying a lookup column, the value in the column looks like, ID#;Text
Example: 15#;MyText

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your query (the syntax is correct). Where are you using it?

Comment: Depending on where/how you are using this query, you can omit the <query></query> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to download the great tool, [CAML Desinger](http://biwug-web.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Caml_designer.aspx). It helps when building CAML queries for usage in web service calls. Point it to your list and you can craft your query against the list data to make sure it functions as expected.

I suspect that its related to the way you're trying to query against a lookup column. I don't have a SP instance in front of me to check right now.

Comment: Thanks guys.it was the values I was searching had space before it.trimmed it and it's all good